# Send picture from android phone to a local web server

Tags: java, android, image, spring, webserver

I've been searching all over and found a bunch of examples of ways to send a picture to a web server. So far none have quite worked for me. Maybe I started in the wrong end but I've already written the code for the controller which is to take care of the received picture.

I'm using a Tomcat web server and written all the code on the server side with Spring Tool Suite with the MVC Framework. The controller is written like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        // store the bytes somewhere
        return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
       } else {
        return "redirect:uploadFailure";
       }
}
```

The .jsp is written like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload a file please</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

So basically what I'd like to know: 
How can I write a class/method that sends a picture from my phone to the web server?

I appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: I am using commons-fileupload

Comment: Use (search for) Apache HTTP components or URLConnection.

Comment: Since I'm not the greatest programmer I would really appreciate if I could get an example code that fits my specific case. Would be awesome!

Comment: I find it hard to apply those on my own!

Comment: Use the search function, there are tons of examples on this site.